# Algorithm or library to plot a dendrogram from a distance matrix

Tags: python, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram, hamming-distance

I am seeking an algorithm or library. I do not want you to write my code.

I have a csv file of genetics SNP information. It is in this format:

```
marker, variety1, variety2, variety3

m1, AA, AA,AG

m2, TT, TT, TT

m3, GG, GG, GG
...
```

I have calculated a distance matrix using the Hamming distance.

```
           variety1, variety2, variety3, 
variety1,   0,        n,        n

variety2,   n,       0,         n

variety3,    n,       n,        0
```

Where `n` is the hamming distance for each variety in column and row.

Is this the matrix I need to draw a dendrogram?

How to do it?

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code? What errors are you getting?  This isn't a "write your code for you" website. http://math.stackexchange.com/ can answer your questions about dendrograms.

Comment: I posted it in order to ask what algorithm or library could I use, I do not meant to you write my code

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html and https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html